# Disable next record button on Dynamics crm 2016 form

Tags: button, crm, ribbon, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using Dynamics Crm 2016 and I need to disable the next/previous record buttons in the form ribbon for particular pages. I've tried using jquery to hide the button, it's just an anchor, but that's not working. See below

[image]

```
$("[title='Next Record (Ctrl+>)']").hide()
```

I have that code on a web resource loaded on the form, set to run on the forn load event but it's not working. It works when run it in the web developer console (IE 11). Can I do this another way, using the Xrm toolkit perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a supported way to do this. JQuery would be one approach, but it would be unsupported and potentially break with any updates pushed by Microsoft.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was unsupported, thanks for your input.